# What is the difference between rm -r and rm -f?

Tags: terminal, rm

From manual:

- -f, --force

  ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
- -r, -R, --recursive

  remove the contents of directories recursively

Though this options description is different, when trying to delete an empty folder (without rmdir for this example) it gives the same result.

`-f` won't print error or anything compared to `-r`, is this the only difference or is there a specific type of situations when one option is better than another or situations where one of this option simply won't work while the other will?

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: On an empty directory they *will* give the same result as there is nothing to delete. Try it on a tree of files and directories, they will give different results.

Comment: What do you mean they give the same result? `rm -r emptydir` removes that directory, `rm -f emptydir` does not. These are two completely different command line options, each doing whatever its documentation says is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the man page in CentOS says:

```
-f, --force
    ignore nonexistent files, never prompt

-r, -R, --recursive
    remove directories and their contents recursively
```

From what I gather (thanks to some comments below), the following is true for the `-r` and `-f` flags:

**-r**

- recursively deletes content of a directory, including hidden files and sub directories
- depending on your configuration, it may ask for permission (for example, when using the `--interactive` flag). Some distributions do this by default.
- can be used to remove a directory, if you want to do so, simply give it the path of the directory (for example: `/path/to/directory`)

**-f**

- does not recursively delete content of a directory, only removes files that directly match the given path (for example `example/file1` or `example/*`).
- Never deletes sub directories
- Never asks for permission, basically the `yes to all` in Windows

Below are a few examples, all of them start with the following structure:

```
example/
  file1
  file2
  file3
  .file
  dir/
    file1
    file2
    file3
    .file
```

I enabled verbosity and interactive mode by default for these examples. Some distros do this while others don't.

**rm example**

```
$ rm example
rm: cannot remove `example': Is a directory
```

As you can see, `rm` does not remove directories by default.

**rm example -f**

```
$ rm example -f
rm: cannot remove `example': Is a directory
```

Using the `-f` flag still doesn't allow it to remove directories.

**rm example -r**

```
$ rm example -r
rm: descend into directory `example'? yes
rm: remove regular empty file `example/file3'? yes
  removed `example/file3'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/file2'? yes
  removed `example/file2'
rm: descend into directory `example/dir'? yes
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/.file'? yes
  removed `example/dir/.file'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/file3'? yes
  removed `example/dir/file3'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/file2'? yes
  removed `example/dir/file2'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/file1'? yes
  removed `example/dir/file1'
rm: remove directory `example/dir'? yes
  removed directory: `example/dir'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/file1'? yes
  removed `example/file1'
rm: remove directory `example'? yes
  removed directory: `example'
```

As you can see, you are asked for permission for every single file and directory, hidden files are also removed.

**rm example/* -f**

```
$ rm example/* -f
rm: cannot remove `example/dir': Is a directory
removed `example/file1'
removed `example/file2'
removed `example/file3'
```

Here, you are not asked for permission, directories are not deleted and neither are hidden files.

**rm example/* -r**

```
$ rm example/* -r
rm: descend into directory `example/dir'? yes
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/.file'? yes
  removed `example/dir/.file'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/file3'? yes
  removed `example/dir/file3'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/file2'? yes
  removed `example/dir/file2'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/dir/file1'? yes
  removed `example/dir/file1'
rm: remove directory `example/dir'? yes
  removed directory: `example/dir'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/.file'? yes
  removed `example/file'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/file1'? yes
  removed `example/file1'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/file2'? yes
  removed `example/file2'
rm: remove regular empty file `example/file3'? yes
  removed `example/file3'
```

Here, the contents of the example directory (not the directory itself) are removed, including hidden files.

Comment: The asterisk _does not_ imply unlimited recursion. If it matches subdirectories (e.g. `example/subdir`), it will not descend any further, and rm will _still_ ignore those directories. (Some shells have `**` which does recurse.)

Comment: Huh, I never knew that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Additionally, `*` usually does not match "dot" files (I suppose it was meant to ignore `.` and `..`, but it ended up ignoring _all_ hidden files), therefore `rm -r dir/*` alone might not necessarily empty the directory; it'd skip `dir/.git` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I have now updated the answer to properly display the differences between `-r` and `-f`, I might have gone a bit overboard though.

Comment: Thanks for everyones input (including other replays)! All answers combined helped me understand this better. Someone asked my OS - I'm using Ubuntu/Linux.

Comment: In my case I was not asked for permissions with the command rm example -r, unlike in your answer. You need -f to bypass permissions like unwritable file eg configured unwritable with chmod 555 file.md

Answer (score 0):

`rm -r mydir` will remove the `mydir` directory with all its contents.

`rm -f mydir` will not remove a directory (neither empty nor with content). It will report an error:

- on BSD/OS X:

  ```
  rm: mydir/: is a directory
  ```
- on GNU/Linux:

  ```
  rm: cannot remove 'mydir': Is a directory
  ```

Possible explanations for the `rm` command behaving regardless of the given arguments (from the most to the least likely):

1. you have a shell alias `rm` defined and it passes some defined parameters (like `-r`) to the `rm` command
2. you are calling a script called `rm` which also passes additional parameters to the actual command
3. you have a custom `rm` executable

You can verify the first two possibilities by executing `/bin/rm -f mydir`.